# what is the c# object to save the data in this formate

Tags: c#, json

I have this string

```
string[] xInBGraph = { "IVR", "Agents", "Abandoned", "Cancelled" };
```

and I have these values:

```
int ivr = 1;
int agents = 2;
int abandoned = 3;
int cancelled = 4;
```

#### What I need

To make an array for each element in the array `xInBGraph` in which the new array should contain one value and the other values are zero. **For example This is how the final result will be**

```
IVR = [ivr =1, 0 , 0 ,0, 0]
Agents = [0, agents=2, 0,0]
Abandoned = [0, 0, abandoned = 3, 0]
Cancelled = [0, 0, 0, cancelled = 0]
```

#### what I have tried

making 4 arrays and fill them in the correct data. It works good. However, my altimate goal is to transfer that final result to a json object. I need to return just on json object. but in my case, which is 4 arrays, I must return 4 json objects which is not good for my situation. I need to return just on json object. So, what is the object in c# that can have the mentioned data and can be transfer to one json object?

#### I am using json.net library so I can easily change any c# object to json object

#### Edit

I made these four arrays:

```
int[] ivrArray = { Tivr, 0, 0, 0};
int[] agentsArray = { 0, tTotalCallsByAgent, 0, 0 };
int[] abandonedArray = { 0, 0, tTotalAbandoned, 0};
int[] canceledArray = { 0, 0, 0, Tcancel};
```

Now all I need is something to save the label of each array and the array in one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you use a Dictionary. Specifically,

```
Dictionary<string,int[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string,int[]>()
{
    { "IVR", new int[] {1,0,0,0} },
    { "Agents", new int[] {0,2,0,0} },
    { "Abandoned", new int[] {0,0,3,0} },
    { "Cancelled", new int[] {0,0,0,0} },    
}
```

Comment: I copied your code, but I got a lot of red errors. for example, `no overload for method take 1 argument` and `invalid anoymous type member declared` ... why please?

Comment: please give me a few minutes to fix it. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: could you follow me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028526/c-sharp-how-to-change-array-to-array-or-arrays

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are expecting

```
    string[] xInBGraph = { "IVR", "Agents", "Abandoned", "Cancelled" };

    List<string[]> final = new List<string[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < xInBGraph.Count(); i++)
    {
        List<string> array = new List<string>();
        for (int x = 0; x < xInBGraph.Count(); x++)
        {
            if (x == i)
            {
                array.Add(xInBGraph[i].ToString() + "=" + x);
            }
            else
            {
                array.Add("0");
            }
        }
        final.Add(array.ToArray());
    }
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(final, Formatting.Indented);
```

***Output***
`[ [ "IVR=0", "0", "0", "0" ], [ "0", "Agents=1", "0", "0" ], [ "0", "0", "Abandoned=2", "0" ], [ "0", "0", "0", "Cancelled=3" ] ]`