# c# how to change array to array or arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have this code:

```
int[] ivrArray = { 1, 0, 0, 0};
int[] agentsArray = { 0, 2, 0, 0 };
int[] abandonedArray = { 0, 0, 3, 0};
int[] canceledArray = { 0, 0, 0, 4};
Dictionary<string, int[]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[]>()
            {
                { "IVR", ivrArray },
                { "Agents", agentsArray },
                { "Abandoned", abandonedArray },
                { "Cancelled", canceledArray },    
            };
```

The output is

```
{
  "IVR": [
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ],
  "Agents": [
    0,
    2,
    0,
    0
  ],
  "Abandoned": [
    0,
    0,
    3,
    0
  ],
  "Cancelled": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    4
  ]
}
```

Is there anyway so the output will be like this:

```
"Cancelled":[
   [0],
   [0],
   [0],
   [4]
]
```

**So each element is array of one element**

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan that is a library that changes that c# object to json. it does't matter what the object is. It can change any object to json object. it is json.net library. but my question is how to make that c# object contains array of arrays , not just arrays. got me ?

Comment: Are you asking how to rewrite the code so that it creates a set of `int[][]` instead of `int[]`, or asking how to write code which converts the given `int[]` to `int[][]`?

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan the first one, hot to change int[] to int[][],i tried myself to do like this: `int[][] ivrArray = { [1], [0], [0], [0]};` but I got syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can re-project your arrays to a `Dictionary<string, int[][]>` like so:

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[][]>
    {
       {"IVR", ivrArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
       {"Agents", agentsArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
       {"Abandoned", abandonedArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
       { "Cancelled",canceledArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()}
    };
```

(and I guess if you didn't want the local vars, then

```
 ...
   {"IVR", new [] { 1, 0, 0, 0 }.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
 ...
```

Comment: can i say `Dictionary<string, int[][]> dictionary` instead or `var dictionary` ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Y, sure, although the `var` variable is still strongly and correctly typed to `Dictionary<string, int[][]>` :)

Comment: could you help me here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23029743/how-to-add-element-to-array

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this using `Jagged Arrays` concept:

for example:

```
int[] list1 = new int[4] { 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] list2 = new int[4] { 5, 6, 7, 8};
int[] list3 = new int[4] { 1, 3, 2, 1 };
int[] list4 = new int[4] { 5, 4, 3, 2 };

int[][] lists = new int[][] {  list1 ,  list2 ,  list3 ,  list4  };
```

and in dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, int[][]> items= new Dictionary<string, int[][]>;
```

here is **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)** documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: in this way, i lost the label in the dictinary

Comment: you need to make dictionary like: <string,int[][]>

Comment: As strautLC also posted