# how to add element to array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have these arrays

```
int[] ivrArray = { 1, 0, 0, 0};
int[] agentsArray = { 0, 2, 0, 0 };
int[] abandonedArray = { 0, 0, 3, 0};
int[] canceledArray = { 0, 0, 0, 4};
```

and I used this dictionary:

```
 Dictionary<string, int[][]> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int[][]>
            {
                {"IVR", ivrArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
                {"Agents", agentsArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
                {"Abandoned", abandonedArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()},
                { "Cancelled",canceledArray.Select(_ => new[] {_}).ToArray()}
            };
```

the result **after changing it to json** is:

```
{
  "IVR": [
    [1],
    [0],
    [0],
    [0]
  ],
  "Agents": [
    [0],
    [2],
    [0],
    [0]
  ],
  "Abandoned": [
    [0],
    [0],
    [3],
    [0]
  ],
  "Cancelled": [
    [0],
    [0],
    [0],
    [4]
  ]
}
```

you can see that each element in the JSON is array like this `[[0],[0],[0],[4]]`

I need to add another value to each element in that array, so the result will be this:

```
[[1325376000000,0],[1328054400000,0],[1330560000000,0],[1333238400000,0]]
```

How can I do that?

These values are static for all the four arrays.

Comment: Didn't you asked amost the same quesiton 2 hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028526/c-sharp-how-to-change-array-to-array-or-arrays

Comment: And aside from that, it *really* feels like you should be creating a new type with properties for IVR, agents, abandoned etc. Then you could just have *one* collection.

Comment: Just add other value when you create the array: new[] {otherValue, _}

Comment: @SonerGönül no that is a completely differenct question

Comment: @sjkm could you give me an answer with that please?

Comment: Where do your other values (1325376000000, etc.) come from?

Comment: @KevinS it is static, i want them static

Comment: Are they in an array somewhere?  In some other collection?  How do you choose which static value is supposed to be paired with the entries?

Comment: @KevinS the first value of the first array is always `1325376000000`. the first vaule of the second array is always `1328054400000` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another value when you create the array: `new[] {otherValue, _}`

Answer (score 1):

do it like this:

```
dictionary.Add("new values", new[] 
                             { 
                               new[] {123, 0}, 
                               new[] {123, 0}, 
                               new[] {123, 0}, 
                               new[] {123, 0}
                              });
```

Comment: so I need to do that for the four elements which are `ivr`, `agents`, `abandont` and `canceled`, isn't there a generic way to do that? like the one I gave in the question

Answer (score 1):

JSON serializers will serialize `List<T>` as *JSON arrays*, thus using lists will be better than *arrays of arrays*.

Your dictionary should be `Dictionary<string, List<List<int>>>`, and you'll be able to obtain a sub-list and add items:

```
dict["some"][0].Add(0);
```